# Display the month and number of quotations received in each month

Tags: sql

Display the month and number of quotations received in each month.
I used this query but the final output is differnet than my output.

```
select distinct To_char(QDate,'Month') as Month,count(QuotationId)as QuotationCount 
from Quotation group by Qdate
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: I have QuotationID as Q1001,Q1002....Q1013 and QDate as 15-Oct-14,18-Oct-2014....16-Jun-14. I have to display the month and number of quotations received in each month from Quoatation Table.I have provided the expected output image link in question.

Comment: We don't want links or images with information, a well asked question should contain this info as text  in the question. Text can be searched or easily used to test queries, images can not. Also don't post additional info as comments, add it to your question instead so it is more easily accessible for peoples reading your question.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(Qdate,'Month') AS "MONTH",
       COUNT(*) AS "QUOTATIONCOUNT" 
       FROM quotation 
       GROUP BY TO_CHAR(Qdate,'Month');
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `To_char(QDate,'Month')` in `group by` clause

```
select To_char(QDate,'Month') as Month,count(QuotationId)as QuotationCount  
from Quotation group by To_char(QDate,'Month')
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want the data ordered by chronological month, then:

```
select to_char(QDate, 'Month') as Month, count(*) as QuotationCount 
from Quotation
group by to_char(QDate, 'Month')
order by to_char(QDate, 'MM);
```

In some databases, you can use the column alias defined in the `SELECT`:

```
group by Month
```